# Can Pebbles StringLoader be reused to load different templates?

Tags: java, template-engine

We are using pebble engine, I know that the PebbleEngine instance can be reused to parse different templates. In my case I am setting the loader of the engine to a StringLoader instance initially and reusing the same engine to process several different templates. My concern is can the StringLoader instance be reused to load different templates? Or should I set a new instance as the loader every time I need to process a different template? I tried reading the API doc and a google search but still can't find a solid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the StringLoader is a stateless class that can be re-used over and over without issue. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/mbosecke/pebble/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mitchellbosecke/pebble/loader/StringLoader.java) for that class you will see how little it actually does. There's no need to create a new StringLoader with every template.

This advice can apply to any of the loaders. Their job is to find a template based off of a name and immediately return a "Reader" object for that template; nothing more, nothing less. They have no memory of the previous templates that they've found, so in that regards they are stateless, and can be immediately re-used with a different template.